# QThread, moveToThread() or another approach?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am developing a GUI application for multithreaded video processing. As a result I realized that I am absolutely confused about different ways to implement threads in Qt and that I need help in order to organize the knowledge gained from documentation and rather contradictory articles (I followed the recommendations from the bottom table in [this article](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-technologies.html)).

The idea is this: there are ReadingThread for reading frames from video and ProcessingThread where the initial processing of frames is performed and tasks with the necessary algorithms for processing the received frames are launched (probably sounds overcomplicated but that's not the question). Both theads are declared in the main thread.

ReadingThread fills the buffer with frames from the video file. This thread is inherited from QThread: an infinite loop in run() which ends when the video ends or stops. There are no problems with this flow, it works exactly as intended. The mentioned tasks are implemented as QRunnable what also suits me completely. But I don't know what to do with the second stream which takes quite a long time to process each frame.

Initially I wanted to inherit QThread again with an infinite loop that would alternately process the images received from ReadingThread:

```
void run() override
{
   // some pseudocode
   while(!isInterruptRequested)
   {
      if(!isImageInProcessing)
         doSomeProcessing();
   }
}
```

But in this case slots will be executed in the main thread where ProcessingThread was initialized. And it leads to problems because this thread must receive signals from other threads. Apparently it is better to use moveToThread() but what I need to do in this case? Also use an infinite loop? If so, how? Or is it better to create a new Worker and move it to the stream for each new frame of the video? How much will this affect performance if such a Worker turns out to be quite heavy storing a lot of processing parameters and all that? The need to receive signals also stops me from using QtConcurrent/QRunnable. But this can be fixed by double inheritance or by adding an emitter QObject that would process signals but is it worth it to overcomplicate?

I'm definitely confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing seems to be the problem of the producer-consumer. A lot of documents are available online.

You have one thread for the I/O, and another thread that takes those frames and processes them in parallel. The pipeline may even be longer. A possible solution to do this is to simply have a QThread subclass that keeps reading the file (as you did), and places these frames in a queue, probably a blocking queue. Another QThread subclass dequeues frames from the blocking queue and does its processing. You can have more of these if you want, all getting frames from the queue.

I wrote this for the purpose: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils/blob/master/lqtutils_bqueue.h.

Of course many other approaches exist.